# Bootstrap navbar toggle button disappears on smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar totally disappears and I am only left with the text in the `navbar-brand` class. I don't even get the toggle button.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(171, 106, 106, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(27, 219, 81, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(14, 145, 40, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Image</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It is probably some minor detail but I am missing it regardless of the tutorials.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu is not disappearing, you are setting it's color to white in your custom css (last few kines of your code). I changed it to red here.

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(171, 106, 106, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(27, 219, 81, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(14, 145, 40, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: red;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Image</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea on how I could add a button in to the nav bar? I added one. It gets aligned top. Instead of begin aligned vertically centre. I have an image so I have set the line-height to 56px.

Comment: If you have your navbar set to fix height. then you could set button's margins.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle of the new code which includes this button

Comment: Hi, it's https://jsfiddle.net/bzzvgo7r/. Thank you for the help. The button gets out of position when it is not collapsed

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you set the color to `#ffffff` so it's not disappearing just because of same background color not visualizing. Just changed to `#000000` and it looks fine.

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(171, 106, 106, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(27, 219, 81, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(14, 145, 40, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #000000;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #000000;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Image</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: rgba(171, 106, 106, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: rgba(27, 219, 81, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: rgba(14, 145, 40, 1);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
  background: #ccc;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Image</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```